# Python Tcp server call functions with parameters

Tags: python, tcpclient, tcpserver

I'm looking for a better way to call functions with or without parameters from a tcpclient. There doesn't seem to be a set way.

What I'm doing now.

From the client side i send a string like:

```
server#broadcast#helloworld
```

and from the server:

```
    commands = []
    data = self.request.recv(BUFF)
    commands = data.split('#')
    if commands[0] == 'server':
        if commands[1] == 'stop':
            serverStop()
        if commands[1] == 'broadcast':
            sendtoall(commands[2])

    if commands[0] == 'application':
        if commands[1] == 'doStuff':
            doStuff(commands[2], commands[3])
```

From the client a send a string with a command#sub-command#parm#parm, and then split it at the server end and call the function.
This manner works but calling functions and error checking will becomes redundant pretty fast.

I want to keep error checking at the server side. It should work with functions with or without parameters, and with any amount of parameters.

If you have a better way to call functions from a client please share.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Note that you can avoid unnecessary checks in the above code by using `if-elif` blocks instead of `if` followed by another `if`.

Comment: Do you have a protocol that you are using for your tcpclient? Is it a stateful protocol or a stateless protocol?

Answer (score 1):

You should structure your program differently depending on what you want to accomplish and what your network protocol looks like. I'm assuming you're using a custom stateless protocol for this example.

```
commands = []
data = self.request.recv(BUFF)
commands = data.split('#')
process_commands(commands)

def process_commands(commands):
    """
    Determines if this is a server or application command.
    """
    if commands[0] == 'server':
        process_server_command(commands[1:])
    if commands[0] == 'application':
        process_application_command(commands[1:])

def process_server_command(commands):
    """
    because I truncated the last list and removed it's 0 element we're
    starting at the 0 position again in this function.
    """
    if commands[0] == 'stop':
        serverStop()
    if commands[0] == 'broadcast':
        sendtoall(commands[1])

def process_application_command(commands)
    if commands[0] == 'doStuff':
        doStuff(commands[1], commands[2])
```

This structure removes the nested if statements and makes it easier to see what the control paths of your code are. It'll also make adding `try` `except` blocks much easier (which you'll need if you're using straight sockets).

Answer (score 1):

Why dont use RPC protocoll? In this case you don't need to parse strings.

Here is the Server

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer

def add(a, b):
    return a+b

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 1234))
print "Listening on port 1234..."
server.register_function(add, "add")
server.serve_forever()
```

And the client

```
import xmlrpclib
print 'start'
proxy = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:1234/")
print "3 + 4 is: %s" % str(proxy.add(3, 4))
```